# Error when using a generic type with a constraint in Typescript - 2536

Tags: typescript

I have the following types:

```
interface IFilterField <T extends FilterFieldValue > {
    defaultValue: T
    displayStr?: string
}

interface IFilterFields = {
   costMax: IFilterField<number>
   costMin: IFilterField<number>
   .....
}>
```

When I try to type an object that will link between the filterField and the type of its` value, this works:

```
export type IFiltersState<FiltersKeys extends keyof IFilterFields> = {
    [K in keyof FiltersKeys]: IFilterFields["costMin"|"costMax"]["defaultValue"]
```

}

But this fails:

```
export type IFiltersState<FiltersKeys extends keyof IFilterFields> = {
   [K in keyof FiltersKeys]: IFilterFields[K]["defaultValue"]
}
```

Even though the constraint is pretty much the same.

Error:

```
[ts] Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'IFilterFields'. [2536]
[ts] Type '"defaultValue"' cannot be used to index type 'IFilterFields[K]'. [2536]
```

Why is this error occuring?

How can I acheive the purpose of a mapped type, which follows this principles: A new type T2 has some of the keys of type T1, and for each such key typeof T1[key] equals typeof T2[key][SomeFieldName]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my error. Since `FiltersKeys` is already a union of keys/strings, there is a reduntand keyof in `[K in keyof IfilterFields]`.

Comment: Should I delete this question altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Because FiltersKeys is extended from IFilterFields, therefore it could contain different keys. You can use

```
export type IFiltersState<FiltersKeys extends keyof IFilterFields> = {
    [K in keyof IFilterFields]: IFilterFields[K]["defaultValue"]
}
```